# Django auth and Postman requests

Tags: django, authentication, postman

How do I authenticate a Django user, when making requests with Postman? I am not using Django Rest framework, just the standard dango.cont.auth system. In Postman you have the following options for authentication: Basic Auth, OAuth, and Custom. In custom I can add some headers.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

please try following image.
key   : Authorization
value : OAuth TOKEN

[image]

Comment: where do I get the OAuth token from?